# How can I create automatic <div> tags everytime I add a new picture in the image folder?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an image folder which contains many jpeg images. I am displaying them in `<div>` tags in my html code. All I want to achieve is that whenever I add a new image in the folder it automatically creates a `<div>` tag in the code. I need your help on this

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 2):

There is no pure CSS way to do this. This would be the arena of php, if you're talking about a server-side folder of pictures, or javascript if the images are uploaded client-side.

Comment: He has PHP in his tags so I assume we can use PHP :)

Comment: ah, but jQuery too!

Comment: jQuery has nothing to do with his question... I made an edit, just waiting for approval.

Comment: +1 - you are *not* feeding people with code, while they haven't tried *anything*. This *is* the appropriate answer to the question, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one sample code for creating multiple . Try if you can use this one in your code

```
<?php   
$dir = "classes/1961/*";
foreach(glob($dir) as $file)
      {
         ?>
              <div class="cell-1-9">
                   <img src="<?php echo $file ?>">
                   <p>Dylan Miller</p>
              </div>
          <?php
      }
```

?>

Comment: This is the same as my reply :>

Comment: yes, seems like you post it while I was typing :)

Comment: Yeah, probably ^^

Comment: @Benni To be exact, his answer **is** different. So, absolutly valid.

Comment: Touché @Nytrix. Just to make it clear, i did not want to be rude. It was rather a little joke :)

Answer (score 0):

As you have provided the PHP-tag, I assume PHP is fine here. Just replace your `<div>`s with this code:

```
<!-- ... -->
<?php
    $files = scandir('./images');
    foreach($files as $file) {
        echo "<div><img src=\"images/$file\"/></div>";
    }
?>
<!-- ... -->
```